# Add Vuforia Area Target Database at runtime

Tags: vuforia

my question is if it is possible to load an Area Target from a local database at runtime and if so, how do I do it (Unity Project).

My usecase is the following:
I want to develop an app where the user can connect to a web server where sensor data can be retrieved. With panels that the user can freely place in the environment, this information should be displayed in the 3D world. To avoid that every user has to deploy his own app via Untiy to load the area target, it would be great if he could load his own 3D environment (Area Target Database) directly in the app where he places his sensors (placement and resolving I have already done successfully).

In pictures, here's what I'm trying to do via script at runtime:

[Area Target in Unity Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFGgs.png)

if anyone can help me, i would be very happy, it is for my bachelor thesis.

I honestly haven't read through all the documentation yet, but found the following:

```
AreaTargetBehaviour areaTargetBehaviour = new AreaTargetBehaviour();
areaTargetBehaviour = vuforiaBehaviour.ObserverFactory.CreateAreaTarget(databasePath, "AppTest");
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to get this to work, it tells me the path is wrong, however I have specified it as it is here: [text](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverFactory.html#a618b8a8a914b5c82a653f69e02b583ce)
described. Quite possibly that is not the correct path or method at all either, hence my question.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation here? https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity

Comment: @emay Hey, thanks for your answer.
yes, I also found this at some point, and it also sounded very promising to me. However, I always get the error code: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR. The paths are as described here: https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverFactory.html#a618b8a8a914b5c82a653f69e02b583ce and I have tried others as well. A completely new project was not the solution either. The StreamingAssets folder is also created in a new project only when you already add a database via the editor.

Comment: @emay However, I actually want to do this at runtime, so I created it manually. Maybe this is the error, but I don't know how else to store the database correctly, since the documentation explicitly says to store it relative to the StreamingAssets folder....
I don't understand why it seems to be so complicated to load a new database or replace an existing one during runtime. I'm sure I'm not the first person to try this.

Comment: @TobiasP. suggest that you review the Area Targets Test App for HoloLens: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/tool. Although I haven't used it recently, I recall that it had an option to load device databases at runtime. You could use this as source code as a reference for how to use the APIs